# Quartz.net on Azure The time zone ID 'Coordinated Universal Time' was not found

Tags: azure, timezone, utc, quartz.net, azure-worker-roles

I'm using Quartz.Net on Azure worker role (hosted in west europe zone) and for some reason my schedulder is not working throwing this error:

> An error occurred while scanning for the next trigger to fire.
>   Couldn't acquire next trigger: Couldn't retrieve trigger: The time
>   zone ID 'Coordinated Universal Time' was not found on the local
>   computer.

The same scheduler with the same configuration is working when hosted in my azure website application. any idea ?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this question is related http://stackoverflow.com/q/15430368/57428

Comment: Looking closly the issue is related to TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id returning 'Coordinated Universal Time' instead of 'UTC'.

Comment: The reason the code was working on the web app (hosted in azurewebsites) and not on the worker role is that TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id is returning 'GMT Standard Time' in the web role. Both web app and worker roles are deployed to the Azure 'West Europe' data center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually went ahead and exported the key/value for **"UTC"** as a template and edited it using the name **"Coordinated Universal Time"** which satisfies Quartz, but still preserves the original key. Then I just added this command to my deployment.cmd:

```
regedit /s addtutctz.reg
```

Now, I am assured that, even if my instance is reprovisioned or cloud service recreated, the registry key will be merged automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not the best solution but what I did is to create new Virtual Machine on Azure, logged remotely to the VM, deploy my worker and changed the registry keys for UTC. I basically changed the key from 'UTC' to ''Coordinated Universal Time' and that sorted my problem. Now Quartz.Net is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by creating the triggers on a specific TimeZone:

```cs
    private static ITrigger BuildTriggerForEveryDayAtSpecifiedTime(int hour, int minutes)
    {
        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");

        return TriggerBuilder
                        .Create()
                        .WithIdentity(string.Format("Triggers every Day at {0}:{1}", hour, minutes), "MyJobs")
                        .StartNow()
                        .WithCronSchedule(string.Format("0 {0} {1} ? * *", minutes, hour), csb => csb.InTimeZone(timeZoneInfo))
                        .Build();
    }
```